# Installing GDAL with MrSID fails on Ubuntu

Tags: gdal, ubuntu, mrsid

I'm trying to install GDAL from source on Ubuntu or CentoOS both, but it fails both times. I also tried GDAL 3.0 which did the same thing.

Is there any way easily get GDAL working with MrSID? I can install GDAL with `apt install gdal-bin`, but there is no MrSID support.

I'm using

```
./configure --with-mrsid=/home/centos/gdal-2.4.3/mrsid/Raster_DSDK
make
```

The output of make on Ubuntu is:

```
mrsidstream.h:64:17: warning: âvirtual const char* LTIVSIStream::getID() constâ can be marked override [-Wsuggest-override]
     const char* getID() const;
                 ^~~~~
mrsiddataset.cpp:214:23: warning: âvirtual LT_STATUS MrSIDProgress::setProgressStatus(float)â can be marked override [-Wsuggest-override]
     virtual LT_STATUS setProgressStatus(float fraction)
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../GDALmake.opt:670: recipe for target '../o/mrsiddataset.lo' failed
make[2]: *** [../o/mrsiddataset.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/gdal/gdal-2.4.3/frmts/mrsid'
GNUmakefile:15: recipe for target 'mrsid-install-obj' failed
make[1]: *** [mrsid-install-obj] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/gdal/gdal-2.4.3/frmts'
GNUmakefile:103: recipe for target 'frmts-target' failed
make: *** [frmts-target] Error 2
```

The output of make on CentoOS 7 is:

```
/home/centos/gdal-2.4.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `LizardTech::LTIOFileStream::~LTIOFileStream()'
/home/centos/gdal-2.4.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `LizardTech::LTIOFileStream::initialize(char const*, char const*)'
/home/centos/gdal-2.4.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `LizardTech::LTIMetadataDatabase::~LTIMetadataDatabase()'
/home/centos/gdal-2.4.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `LizardTech::LTIImageStage::read(LizardTech::LTIScene const&, LizardTech::LTISceneBuffer&)'
/home/centos/gdal-2.4.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `LizardTech::MrSIDImageReader::create()'
/home/centos/gdal-2.4.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `LizardTech::LTINavigator::LTINavigator(LizardTech::LTIImage const&)'
/home/centos/gdal-2.4.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `LizardTech::LTINavigator::setSceneAsULWH(double, double, double, double, double)'
/home/centos/gdal-2.4.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `LizardTech::LTIGeoCoord::get(double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&) const'
/home/centos/gdal-2.4.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `LizardTech::LTISceneBuffer::LTISceneBuffer(LizardTech::LTIPixel const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, void**, unsigned int)'
/home/centos/gdal-2.4.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `LizardTech::J2KImageReader::initialize(LizardTech::LTIOStreamInf&, bool, float, bool)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [gdalserver] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/centos/gdal-2.4.3/apps'
make: *** [apps-target] Error 2
```

I just downloaded the SDK from https://www.extensis.com/support/developers
I tried 5.3.1 and 4.8.2.

Comment: I know this issue. My workaround was to convert the MrSID file on a windows machine ... not very elegant though ...

Comment: I'm forced to do the same. OSgeo4w works turnkey, but it's not available on Linux.

Comment: maybe you find help on the GDAL mailing list https://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/gdal-dev

Comment: I'm writing this here because I don't have enough reputation to comment (sorry), but were you able to find a fix? I'm struggling with this exact issue and tried following these tutorials:
1. https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/MrSID
2. https://gist.github.com/oeon/6527004
3. http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Directions-to-get-mrsid-support-in-GQIS-and-other-packages-using-gdal-on-Ubuntu-td3752823.html But none of them work. Please let me know, thanks!

Comment: maybe you can try this : https://trac.osgeo.org/ubuntugis/wiki/TutorialMrSid

Comment: Did you look at travis recipe to get clues e.g https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/ci/travis/trusty_clang/before_install.sh#L51 and https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/ci/travis/trusty_clang/install.sh#L40?

Comment: Does this answer your question?: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/359329/8104

Answer (score 0):

According to this site : https://trac.osgeo.org/ubuntugis/wiki/TutorialMrSid

You need to get the sdk of Lizardtech (which you already did) in order to have MrSid support (proprietary).

Then install gdal and add the plugin with

`sudo gdal-build-mrsid $HOME/Geo_DSK-[version]`

or

`sudo gdal-mrsid-build $HOME/Geo_DSDK-[version]`